# Attempting to convert a prefix command to a slash command - getting "This interaction failed."

Tags: npm, discord, discord.js

Basically, I'm converting one of my regular commands into a slash command. It's just an embedded response, but the issue is that it says "This interaction failed". I read on `deferReply()`, but deferReply doesn't work for me at all, it's supposed to say "bot is thinking.." but doesn't. It does the 3 second "Sending command..." then fails.

Code:

```
const { SlashCommandBuilder, EmbedBuilder } = require('@discordjs/builders');
const wait = require('node:timers/promises').setTimeout;
    
      
       
       

       
        
        let questions = [
            {
                title: "some array you got there!",
            },

        ]

        let suggest = ["some array you got there!",]
        let q = questions[Math.floor(Math.random()*(questions.length))];
        let s = suggest[Math.floor(Math.random()*(suggest.length))];

        module.exports = {
            data: new SlashCommandBuilder()
            .setName('topic')
            .setDescription('gives topics'),
        async execute(interaction, message) {
            interaction.deferReply()

            const user = message.mentions.users.first() || message.author;
       
        const embed = {
        title: `**${q.title}**`,
        author: {
            name: 'chat topic:',
            icon_url: user.avatarURL(),
            url: 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dQw4w9WgXcQ',
        },
        footer: {
            text: `topic requested by: ${message.author.username} ${s}`,
            icon_url: '',
        },
        color: 0x7732a8,
    }

    
           
       
        
       interaction.editReply({ embeds: [embed] });

    }}
```

There's no issues in console, I tried to log, still nothing. Just "This interaction failed."

Comment: @ZsoltMeszaros I read you need to put `await interaction.deferReply` then after `interaction.editReply`, speaking about the embed right above the `interaction.editReply` line.

Comment: But you missed the `await` keyword before `interaction.deferReply ()`. It should work with that.

Comment: @ZsoltMeszaros I've tried that, doesn't work, still says "This application did not respond"

Comment: Have you checked if `execute` run at all?

Comment: @ZsoltMeszaros How would I check that? I tried to log it, nothing popped up. The module.exports part looks right too.

Comment: The problem comes from your slash command handler. because the execute function doesn't execute at all. Show us your interactionCreate event too.